# How is the object created when using ISerializationSurrogate?

Tags: c#, serialization, deserialization, binary-serialization

I use ISerializationSurrogate. In `object SetObjectData(object obj, SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context, ISurrogateSelector selector)` obj will be the empty new object.

the MSDN says:

*The SetObjectData method is called during deserialization. With this method, you can take the empty `Object obj` that has already been created, and enter `SerializationInfo info data` into that object. Constructors are not invoked during deserialization of information and reconstruction of the object.*

My question is: how will the object be created? Perhaps someone can point me to the Code at http://www.sourceof.net where this happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The object is created by the [FormatterServices.GetUninitializedObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.formatterservices.getuninitializedobject.aspx) method. The code where this is called from is [here](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/mscorlib/R/b9d0c578b71509b3.html).

The implementation of `GetUninitializedObject` is deep in the CLR itself, you can see the sources [here](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/e9595bec6df5fbfc9fb8be811f51418c3b9cf945/src/vm/reflectioninvocation.cpp#L2661) if you are really interested.

If you have the sources of the object to de/serialize it is better to implement `ISerializable` and use the special constructor because you can set the readonly fields from there. When using surrogates you can set the read-only fields only by reflection, which is not just slow but requires full trust permission.